# Two persons show up between 8am and 9am, probability that they will find person C that is there from 8:00-8:15

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Persons A and B show up at a school between 8:00-9:00 to study, person C is at school from 8:00 to 8:15, what is the probability:

1)that he will meet both of them
2)that he will meet at least one of them
3)that he will meet exactly one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the involved probability distributions are uniform in the given ranges. The arrival of $A$ and $B$ can be represented as a point in the square $[8,9]\times[8,9]$, hence both $A$ and $B$ arrive at a moment $\in[8,8+\frac{1}{4}]$ with a probability equal to $\frac{1}{16}$, the ratio of the areas of $[8,8+\frac{1}{4}]^2$ and $[8,9]^2$. Similarly, $C$ meets just one person between $A$ and $B$ with a probability equal to $2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{8}$, none of them with a probability equal to $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$.